# C# DataSet, Data Source and Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datagridview

1. So I have this code inside a stored procedure:

   ```
   select * from myTable where email = @email
   ```

   assume that `@email` is `nvarchar(50)` and `email` is a column in the table
2. I have a `DataSet` that has the above stored procedure.
3. I have a `DataGridView` that has it's data source as the dataset which uses the stored procedure.

I want to pass a value to the @email in the stored procedure. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, by calling the procedure with parameter. Can you should the C# code for it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just add appropriate parameter to your `SqlCommand` or whatever you use to get results. It's hard to say more without seeing your actual code sample.

Comment: google C#.NET ADO PARAMETERS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Assuming SqlCommand object 'command', just add the Parameters to it. See [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson07)

```
string Email="Email";
string email="somebody@hotmail.com";
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(Email, email));
```

Of course, your stored Procedure needs to be expecting the parameter also.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_YourStoredProc]
```

(
    @Email          [nvarchar(50)]  =   NULL,
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this one**

```
// Create the command and set its properties.
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "ProcedureName";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
// Add the input parameter and set its properties.
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "@email";
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parameter.Value = textEmail.Text;
// Add the parameter to the Parameters collection. command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```